# SCP equivalent in chef

Tags: linux, azure, chef-infra, scp

I am trying to `scp` a file from a server to another server both on Azure. This is the command I want to replace:

```
cp /tmp/openvpn/EasyRSA-3.0.4/pki/reqs/server.req jkirby29@40.121.47.3:/tmp
```

I have tried remote_file already, I am not sure of anything else that is even close to what I need. Is this one of those where I need to put it in a bash block? I am new to chef so excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: You are trying to copy from one server to another server from a 3rd server and that 3rd server is the one running the Chef cookbook? You could do that in the bash block.. but this seems a bit odd if that file isn't being used for something locally.

Comment: @BrandonMiller No I have server A (for openvpn) and I have server B which the guide I am following says to put the `.key` file on it. Trying to get the file from server A to server B.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww There is no DevOps stack exchange so the choices are the Dev(SO) or Ops(SF) and this is more related to coding than admin work since chef is Ruby code. Thanks for the un-needed downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really something Chef supports. The `remote_file` resource does support SFTP, but it expects to be pulling from a remote server, not pushing as this is. In general this kind of approach leads to a lot of complexity when scaling up/out, like when you need to push to a dozen machines instead of just one, so you need to work out which IPs, which might be changing, etc etc. You can use an `execute` or `script` resource to do it as written though, if that's really what you want.

Comment: This is not so much for a scalable thing, it is for making a single server for us. I am only doing it in chef to make it so others can do it if ever needed and just for me to learn more chef. As for putting in the IPs manually, I am not too worried about that as I said not really scaling past 1 server.

Comment: Then yeah, an `execute` resource is the right thing :)